# internal memory overflow when i gif have many frame ￼

Tags: iphone, ios

i have a gif it is 1.9m,but have 705 frame ,so when i play it,it give me didReceiveMemoryWarning ,and then my app is crash. my gif http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/62037b5ajw1e4w08i5g6og20c808ku0x.gif,and i use

https://github.com/ondalabs/OLImageView

https://github.com/shichangone/SCGifExample  but all give the didReceiveMemoryWarning, and crash.

how to improve the gif image view? i read more,but not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can decompose the one image into many, you can use a CADisplayLink to show them. Better yet make a movie of it and show that instead.